# Finding new position (x,y) after resizing image

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, transform

I have a set of object annotations in bounding box form. I have the x,y and x2y2 coordinations of these bounding boxes. I wish to preprocess the images and resize them using either Matlab's imresize or opencv/python INTER_AREA. No problems there, but I wish to find the new positions of the bounding box  coordinates.

Ideally, I should be able to get the transform matrix from INTER_AREA and apply it to the coordinates but I don't see a way to do this although I have been browsing a ton.

Thanks.

Comment: The transformation has nothing to do with whether you use INTER_AREA or other interpretation. Only the scale factor matters. Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Well I haven't written the code because I am trying to understand. Does not it matter how the resizing algorithm works? Does it resize from (0,0) or the center point? Do I need only polar coordinates? 

Well, I will use something like this
`resize(src, dst, Size(), 0.5, 0.5, interpolation);`

What I am trying to do is downscaling my images which are 854x480 to preferably something that will have the longest edge as 500.Or I will just apply a down scale factor, I don't know say 0.35

Comment: (0, 0) will still be map to (0, 0), so only the scaling factor matters.

Comment: oh right, then it is not translation exactly because of that. Thanks! seems like I was confused so I will just make a x * scale factor , y * scale factor and possibly have to round it up, correct? Many thanks.

Comment: That's right, it's that simple.

Answer (score 8):

You could represent the bboxes as percentages of the original image, then resize the image and convert the bboxes back to image coordinates.

For example:

```
function x1p,y1p,x2p,y2p = toPercentage(img_orig, x1,y1,x2,y2)
    h,w,c = size(img_orig);
    x1p = x1 / w;
    x2p = x2 / w;
    y1p = y1 / h;
    y2p = y2 / h;
```

Once you have these percentages resize your image and then convert the bbox percentages back to coordinates of the resized image.

```
function x1,y1,x2,y2 = toImCoord(img_resized, x1p,y1p,x2p,y2p)
    h,w,c = size(img_resized);
    x1 = x1p * w;
    x2 = x2p * w;
    y1 = y1p * h;
    y2 = y2p * h;
```

Comment: Hi @Sean335, could you please explain as where `size()` is coming from?

Comment: Size is a Matlab built in function, it returns the dimensions of an array.